# Do I need ObservableObject with UIKit?

Tags: swift, uikit, observable, combine

I just want to ask you. Do I need `ObservableObject` as an inheritance in viewModel with UIKit and Combine (without SwiftUI)? I tried it without inheritance and it works. Should I use it or not?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you do not need it when using **Combine** with **UIKit**.

---

Protocols such as `ObservableObject` are made for **SwiftUI** in mind. Basically, all `ObservableObject` does is signal to **SwiftUI** which nodes in the graph have been invalidated and need to be recomputed.